# Espresso test blocked with background thread. Application not idle Exception: "AppNotIdleException."

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-espresso

My android espresso unit test blocked due to some background thread not idle. How can i figure out which thread is blocking my application to execute?

```
        android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 246 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed ASYNC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED.
        at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
        at android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard(Espresso.java:159)
```

Comment: check this plz https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198539/4797289

Answer (score 4):

As a beginning:

> Espresso for Android is perfect and fast test automation framework,
>   but it has one important limitation - you are allowed to operate only
>   inside your app under test context.
>
> From:
>   http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

It means that [`Espresso`](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html) for perform any action needs to operate on main thread of app. It checks when UI thread is `idle()` and if not it waits until UI thread would be idle again.

If UI Thread is not idle too long, it produces `Espressso IdlingResources` errors like [`AppNotIdleException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/AppNotIdleException.html), which means:

> An exception which indicates that the App has not become idle even after the specified duration.

To deal with this problem you need to create your own [`IdlingResource`](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html) method to say `Espresso` when UI thread would be `idle()` for it.

Let's take a look a bit deeper into problem:

> Espresso introduces the concept of `IdlingResource`, which is a simple
>   interface that:
>
> > Represents a resource of an application under test
> >     which can cause asynchronous background work to happen during test
> >     execution
>
> The interface defines **three** methods:
>
> - getName(): must return a non-null string that identifies an idling    resource.
> - isIdleNow(): returns the current idle state of the idling    resource. If it returns true, the onTransitionToIdle() method on the
>     registered ResourceCallback must have been previously called.
> - registerIdleTransitionCallback(IdlingResource.ResourceCallback    callback): normally this method is used to store a reference to the
>     callback to notify it of a change in the idle state.
>
> For example, an implementation for an idling resource that waits for a
>   page to be fully loaded in a WebView will look something like this:
>
> ```
> public class WebViewIdlingResource extends WebChromeClient implements IdlingResource {
>
>     private static final int FINISHED = 100;
>
>     private WebView webView;
>     private ResourceCallback callback;
>
>     private WebViewIdlingResource(WebView webView) {
>         this.webView = checkNotNull(webView,
>                 String.format("Trying to instantiate a \'%s\' with a null WebView", getName())));
>         // Shall we save the original client? Atm it's not used though.
>         this.webView.setWebChromeClient(this);
>     }
>
>     @Override public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
>         if (newProgress == FINISHED && view.getTitle() != null && callback != null) {
>             callback.onTransitionToIdle();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
>         if (webView.getProgress() == FINISHED && callback != null) {
>             callback.onTransitionToIdle();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override public String getName() {
>         return "WebView idling resource";
>     }
>
>     @Override public boolean isIdleNow() {
>         // The webView hasn't been injected yet, so we're idling
>         if (webView == null) return true;
>         return webView.getProgress() == FINISHED && webView.getTitle() != null;
>     }
>
>     @Override public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
>         this.callback = resourceCallback;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> After creating your own custom idling resource, it needs to be
>   registered with Espresso by calling
>   `Espresso.registerIdlingResource(webViewIdlingResource)`.
>
> From:http://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/

If it won't work try to use along with `Espresso` another Google test framework called [`uiatomator`, which may help you to deal with this problem.

Hope it will help

Comment: @AndroidMechanic edited my answer. Could you change your note or sy what I need to improve?

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue. I've coded a DumThreadRule to dump thread in case of test failing. Here's the code if anyone need this :

```
class DumpThreadRule() : TestWatcher() {
    private fun dumpThreads() {
        val threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces()
        threads.forEach {
            System.err.println(it.key.getName() + ": " + it.key.getState())
            for (stackTraceElement in it.key.getStackTrace()) {
                System.err.println("\t" + stackTraceElement)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun failed(e: Throwable?, description: Description?) {
        super.failed(e, description)
        dumpThreads()
    }
}
```

That you can use in your tests :

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var dumpThreadRule = DumpThreadRule()
```

However, in my case, all the threads are either "RUNNABLE", "TIMED_WAITING" or "WAITING". None of them are "RUNNING". Therefore my UI thread should be "IDLE" no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread dump to see what is blocking your app. Sometimes it help when you create more than one thread dump.