# Android espresso cases failed on Huawei phone

Tags: android, android-espresso, huawei-developers

I was following the espresso guide by [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/949489-espresso-testing-and-screen-robots-getting-started), and it works well on Pixel 4:

```
 $ ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 2 tests on Pixel 4 - 11

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 59s
52 actionable tasks: 23 executed, 29 up-to-date
```

But when I tried to run in Huawei Mate 20pro(EMUI 10.1.0), it just got stuck:

```
 $ ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 2 tests on LYA-AL00 - 10
<============-> 97% EXECUTING [3m 44s]
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

And got the same status on Android studio's side:
[image]

Just wondering is there anything that I missed on Huawei's phone?

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486171/14006568

Comment: @shirley Thanks for your reply. The SO question your mentioned doesn't work with my specific case. My cases works in all Snapdragon phones, but failed in Huawei phones. It's weird.